# How SELECT FOR UPDATE in PostgreSQL work?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I run the below query concurrently in pgAdmin to see how SELECT FOR UPDATE run.

The logic is that there will be a limit for number of users for each team. And if the number reach the limit, the insert will be abort.

The script is as below. pg_sleep is to give me time execute the script 2 before script 1 finish.

```
DO $$
declare
    team_user_count INT;

BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Insert start at %', timeofday();
    
    team_user_count := COUNT(user_id) FROM (select user_id from mst_user_team where team_id = 1 FOR UPDATE ) mut;

    if team_user_count >= 30 then
        RAISE NOTICE 'Not accept insert. team_user_count=%', team_user_count;
    else
        RAISE NOTICE 'Accept insert. team_user_count=%', team_user_count;    
        PERFORM pg_sleep(10);    
        -- insert script here
    end if;

    RAISE NOTICE 'Insert done at %', timeofday();

END$$
```

At the start, the number of user will be 29. 2 scripts run concurrently and both successfully insert the data. The notice both indicated that the current number of users is 29. Why is this happen?

My thought is that when script 2 will wait until script 1 end, then execute the select for update query to get the number 30. But, apparently, it already get the data, and just wait until script 1 finish to show the result.

Is my understand correct?

Answer (score 0):

The FOR UPDATE lock in PostgreSQL stops conflicting locks on particular rows, but it does not stop other operations from reading the same data. In your scenario, before obtaining the update lock during the subsequent INSERT process, both scripts are able to view the user count simultaneously. If necessary, think about utilizing explicit advisory locks or other synchronization techniques to facilitate communication between the scripts.
Hope it's helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Like all SQL statements, `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` acquires a snapshot when it starts, that is, it determines which transactions are visible and which aren't. Any rows that you `INSERT` later on aren't visible to the statement, even if they were inserted before the `SELECT` completed.

There is only one exception where a statement can see data that were added after its snapshot was taken: If a statement is blocked by a lock, it waits for the lock to be relinquished, and then **it fetches the latest committed version of the row and checks again if that matches the query condition**. This applies only to rows that were updated, but not rows that were inserted, which leads to [interesting anomalies](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/transaction-anomalies-with-select-for-update/).

Your case is a variant of that: one of the concurrent transactions (let's call it transaction 1) grabs the lock on the rows, while the other (transaction 2) is blocked. Transaction 1 then inserts rows and commits. Transaction 2 fetches the latest versions of the locked rows and sees that they didn't change, but it does not see the new rows that were inserted by transaction 1. So the test is passed, and transaction 2 also inserts some rows, violating the desired constraint.

There is no way to guarantee a constraint like yours, unless you either use the `SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation level or serialize the transactions (for example with an advisory lock).

Answer (score 0):

I'll do an example...

```
CREATE TABLE players( player_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY );
CREATE TABLE teams( 
    team_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    nplayers INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 CHECK( nplayers BETWEEN 0 AND 3 )
);
INSERT INTO players SELECT n FROM generate_series(1,100) n;
INSERT INTO teams SELECT n,0 FROM generate_series(1,100) n;
CREATE TABLE roster(
    team_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES teams(team_id),
    player_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES players(player_id),
    PRIMARY KEY( team_id, player_id )
);
INSERT INTO roster VALUES ( 1,1 ),( 1,2 );
UPDATE teams SET nplayers=(SELECT count(*) FROM roster WHERE roster.team_id=teams.team_id);
SELECT * FROM teams LEFT JOIN roster USING (team_id) WHERE team_id=1;
 team_id | nplayers | player_id
---------+----------+-----------
       1 |        2 |         1
       1 |        2 |         2
```

Now I open two terminals and type on the left one from your question:

```
    BEGIN;
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (select player_id from roster where team_id = 1 FOR UPDATE ) foo;
```

Note count(something) is the number of rows where something is not null, and user_id is not null, so count(*) does the same thing as count(user_id) in this case.

The SELECT FOR UPDATE would have locked the rows in table roster... but that won't help because it won't lock the row that is going to be inserted by the other connection. In fact, if the team has no players, it won't take any locks at all. So that won't work, because the SELECT FOR UPDATE is done on the wrong table. It has to be done on the teams table to make sure both instances lock the same row, which in this case is the team (which also exists). Okay, rollback.

So now to also illustrate Laurenz's answer I open a third terminal and psql instance. The number at the beginning of the line is which psql instance receives the command.

```
1:
    BEGIN;
    SELECT * FROM teams WHERE team_id=1 FOR UPDATE;
 team_id | nplayers
---------+----------
       1 |        2
2:
    BEGIN;
    SELECT * FROM teams WHERE team_id=1 FOR UPDATE;
3:
    BEGIN;
```

Instance 1 got the lock and performed the SELECT, while instance 2 is waiting.

```
1:
    INSERT INTO roster VALUES (1,3);
    UPDATE teams SET nplayers=nplayers+1 WHERE team_id=1;
3:
    SELECT * FROM teams LEFT JOIN roster USING (team_id) WHERE team_id=1 FOR UPDATE OF teams;
    (locked)
1:
    COMMIT;
```

Right after the COMMIT, instance 2 gets the lock and responds:

```
2:
 team_id | nplayers
---------+----------
       1 |        3
```

So the application would abort the insert. Meanwhile the reporting query in instance 3 goes on...

```
2: 
    ROLLBACK
3:
 team_id | nplayers | player_id
---------+----------+-----------
       1 |        3 |         1
       1 |        3 |         2
```

So, instance 2 got the latest value and will decide not to insert. That's because both instances 1 and 2 took a FOR UPDATE lock on the same row (the team), that works.

However, instance 3 took its snapshot at BEGIN when the third row in roster did not exist, so it does not see it. But as it had to wait for a lock, after doing so it got the new updated version of the row in teams. So we have 3 players in teams, but only 2 in roster, which is inconsistent.

Visibility is one reason why you can't enforce this type of constraint with a count() in a trigger unless you put an exclusive lock on the table. However with a "nplayers" column in table teams, it is possible... but then it has to be kept up to date and consistent, preferably via triggers, which is not necessarily obvious.

There's another way which is bulletproof but a bit ugly.

```
    CREATE TABLE roster( 
        team_id integer not null references teams(team_id),
        player_id integer not null references players(player_id),
        slot integer not null CHECK (position BETWEEN 1 AND 30),
        UNIQUE( team_id, slot ),
        PRIMARY KEY( team_id, player_id )
    )
```

This hacks it into a UNIQUE constraint. Since slot is an int between 1 and 30 included, there can only be 30 slots in which to put a player in the team, and the UNIQUE constraint enforces that no two players can have the same slot in the same team.

It complicates things, because on insertion you must find a free slot. And if there is a concurrent insertion to the same slot, then only one of the inserts will succeed and the other(s) will fail the unique constraint.